# jQuery animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
function toggle() 
    {
    $("#Layer4").animate( { width:"20%"}, 1000 );
    $("#Layer6").animate( { width:"20%"}, 1000 );
    }
```

Now what happens is that `Layer4` and `Layer6` witness some animation, but interestingly the height changes and not the width.

Also, after a second, the original dimensions are restored.

Why is this happening ?

--

```
<body onload="open()">
  <div id="Layer4">
    <img src="friend-line.jpg" width="243" height="380" />
  </div>
  <div id="Layer5" onClick="toggle()">
    <img src="toggle_in.jpg" width="7" height="50" />
  </div>
  <div id="Layer6"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you upload all of the code please?

Comment: <body onload="open()">
<div id="Layer4"><img src="friend-line.jpg" width="243" height="380" /></div>
<div id="Layer5" onClick="toggle()"><img src="toggle_in.jpg" width="7" height="50" /></div>
<div id="Layer6"></div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you'll have consistent results using %.  Try using pixels instead.  If you must use % make sure that you don't have a surrounding div which the width is also set in %.  My guess is that that is the case.

Comment: yep,tried using px. The dimensions still get reset within seconds :/

Comment: any idea as to why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reduce the size of the div by less than the img tag.  If you want that behavior you'll need to replace the img tag with a background-image style.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing images instead of their containers...

```
$('#Layer4 img').animate( { width:'20%'}, 1000 );
$('#Layer6 img').animate( { width:'20%'}, 1000 );
```

And even better, use pixels instead of percents, as already suggested.